# Tuple to List Python

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

I have a tuple like this

```
rows = ((1L, 100000L, 'logo', '0'), (2L, 100000L, 'menu', '0'))
```

And I want to turn it into this

```
[[1L, 100000L, 'logo', '0'], [2L, 100000L, 'menu', '0']]
```

Here is what I am trying

```
for idx, val in enumerate(rows):
    print list(rows[idx])
```

And

```
for idx, val in enumerate(rows):
     print list(val)
```

but neither prints out anything and there is no error. It just doesn't do anything. I know the variable `rows` has this value because I print it out before I go thought the loop.

How can I turn the tuple in to an array of arrays?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
list(map(list, rows))
```

The built-in `list` converts anything into a list that is iterable, i.e. you can write a `for`loop for it. The `map` applies the function `list` to the tuples inside the tuple.

An alternative would be a nested list comprehension:

```
[[x for x in t] for t in rows]
```

List comprehensions are essentially loops in one line. They can only contain expressions. "Normal" loops can contain statements and are typically better suited for multi-line solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
new_rows = []
for i in rows:
    rows.append(list(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
>>> rows = ((1L, 100000L, 'logo', '0'), (2L, 100000L, 'menu', '0'))
>>> [list(x) for x in rows]
[[1L, 100000L, 'logo', '0'], [2L, 100000L, 'menu', '0']]
```